Control Blending Mode of the Color Mix node through the custom driver
Could somebody point me out on how to control the Blending mode of Color Mix nodes through the Custom Properties driver? I want to be able to choose between Mix, Multiply and Add parameters.
I have been creating custom drivers to change floats and colors, but never to pick a value from the list. Can't find any advice on the topic.

Please ask a new question instead of editing the question into a different one.

@3DBear: Editing questions to ask another question is pretty unfair and unthankful to those, who already answered your question. Also consider clicking the confirm button if the answer helped you. As you know you can open as many questions as you want. Thx for your understanding.

I just emphasized what was already in the question. I did not ask for a totally new things, but rather prioritized the different parts of the first question

Don't understand me wrong, I don't accuse you of anything, just look at the difference of the changes you made: https://i.imgur.com/CjuxJTI.png - you removed over half of words and then added majority of the new form of the post - of course metrics like this (amount of words removed/added) can't possibly mean the change is incorrect, but it really should make you reconsider if this is the edit you want to make :D And I think both me and Chris agree the edit was actually changing the meaning of the question too much. Simply ask a new question and link to this one for context.

You can use usual workflow: right-click a field and choose "Copy as a New Driver", and right-click another field and choose "Paste Driver". The value to be used is the index of the option:


LOL! I did not notice that I was already controlling it through a custom property integer driver. =DDD Thanks. Are there any tricks to limit the amount of options though? Instead of going through all the list, would be cool to skip some of the blending modes.

@3DBear x if x < 4 else x+1?

@3DBear: Please click on the checkmark left of Markus answer, if it helped you. Please do NOT ask further questions in the comments, but open a new questions because other people cannot (!) find these questions/answers in the comments and so these are useless for other people who are searching for answers. Thx for your understanding.
